# Simulate ftp with serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, ftp, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have cameras that support FTP. I want to create a server that can be connected via FTP and receive files sent from the cameras. The received files would be processed and disposed. I need an FTP server which implements only the commands that are required for login and receiving the files. Other commands such as `mkdir`, `ls` might be ignored or simulated with database if needed.

I think I might need storage or at least a database to implement it. Is it possible to simulates FTP in such a manner on AWS Lambda or other serverless services?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Maybe It is not a Programming question, But Your link says:
"if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @KaiBurjack Yes, AWS Transfer Family is really expensive (at least 216$ per month) for my personal project. And will not cover all my needs. I'd better run EC2 instance

Comment: How is asking, if some cloud service can be used as an FTP server *"unique to software development"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am asking, Can I develop software that runs on serverless and can receive files over FTP

Comment: *"Serverless service"* is quite vague, that can hardly be answered. And asking for service recommendation is explicitly forbidden on Stack Overflow anyway. I'm sure you cannot implement FTP server in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to suggest a good solution/advice without context and requirement details, but it might be worth to look at the article [SFTP access to Google Cloud Storage](https://medium.com/google-cloud/sftp-access-to-google-cloud-storage-43ffd6134b0e) by [Neil Kolban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738915/kolban).